# Write to Stdout without newline in sequelize migrations

Tags: sequelize.js, stdout, sequelize-cli

We have a long running migration to run in sequelize that we will run using the migration framework.

I'm concerned this migration will cause our CI environment to give up on the job because it cancels jobs if there's no output to the console for a significant period of time.

I was hoping to just use `process.stdout.write('.')` to print a dot every so often so as not to gum up the console with thousands of new lines, but to give the CI environment an indication that the task is progressing.

Unfortunately, when run from within a sequelize migration, the stdout seems to have been modified to append a newline.

Is there any way to work around this?

Output of versions at the start of migrations is
Sequelize [Node: 8.11.4, CLI: 2.8.0, ORM: 3.34.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution I was unable to find one. I ended up just using a counter and doing a `console.log()` every 100th iteration which kept activity within the timeout without making the console excessively long